# how to force R to execute what's inside of quotes?

Tags: r, rlang

I have a vector of values, where each element is between quotes "..."
What I want is that R get rid of the quotes and execute what is inside.
In my particular case, what I have between the quotes are elements inside a huge list.
Notice the following example:
The first element is "list_jsons[[1]]['description']$description$title".
Naturally, if I copy and then paste:

list_jsons[[1]]['description']$description$title

in the Console, I get what I want, the output.
But what I want is to automatize that.
So far, I tried the command glue(), that removes the quotations marks. So I tried glue(glue(list_......))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to convert the character elements to expressions and evaluate.
We can do that with the `rlang`package. For code stored inside a tex element called "character_element", we can use `eval(parse_expr(character_element))`. To do it to an entire vector, use a looping function or `Vectorize`. lapply will output a list with the output of all expressions in the vector.

```
library(rlang)

lapply(your_vector, function(x) eval(parse_expr(x)))
```

Or with purrr:map

```
library(purrr)
library(rlang)

map(your_vector, ~eval(parse_expr(.x)))
```

An example:

```
text<-c("iris[1:10, 1:2]$Sepal.Width", "mtcars[mtcars$mpg<median(mtcars$mpg),]")

lapply(text, function(x) eval(parse_expr(x)))

[[1]]
 [1] 3.5 3.0 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1

[[2]]
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
```

With `Vectorize`:

```
Vectorize(function(x) eval(parse_expr(x)))(text)
```

As pointed out by @Donald Seinein in the comments, there is base-R solution with `eval(parse(text=x))`:

```
lapply(text, function(x) eval(parse(text = x))
```

Comment: `lapply(text, function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))` if you don't want the `rlang` dependency and list elements are length 1 character vector